# How do I call the basic WordPress header files?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, fatal-error

I'm making a custom form action.php and currently it looks like this:

```
<?php
// Collect Data
$first      = $_POST["first_name"];
$last       = $_POST["last_name"];
$email      = $_POST["email"];
$pass       = $_POST["password"];
$pass2      = $_POST["confirm_password"];
$cat        = $_POST["category"];
$tAndC      = $_POST["terms_and_conditions"];
$privacy    = $_POST["privacy_policy"];
$newsletter = $_POST["newsletter"];
die();
?>
```

Essentially nothing going on - the problem though is when I want to call a WordPress hook such as something like this:

```
$user_name = $email;
$user_id = username_exists( $user_name );
```

it returns an error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function username_exists()...

I'm aware that there are probably header files I am not calling for the 'undefined function' to actually run.

I have tried adding at the top of the page: `wp_head();` - but I get the following error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function wp_head()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include wp-load.php file (in the root of your wordpress installation) in your php script file like so,

```
require_once("/path/to/wordpress/wp-load.php");
```

you will have to provide the abspath of the wp-load file, now you can use all the functions of wordpress in your php script.

Answer (score 2):

Include

```
$base_dir = dirname(dirname(__FILE__));
require_once($base_dir."/wp-load.php");
```

With your desired path and check